# congruence class

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Just wanted to know if I was on the right track with this answer.

```
([1] - [6]) * ([5] + [7]) 


LHS = 1 = 1(mod11)                          
    = 6 = 6(mod11)
    -5 = 6(mod11) 
    = [6]  



 RHS = 5 = 5(mod11) 
       = 7 = 7(mod11) 
       5 + 7 = 12 = 1(mod11) 
       = [1] 
   Final = [6] * [1]
```

Comment: That all looks correct! Nice job -- just make sure to say what $[6]*[1]$ is.

Comment: Perfectly good.  Note;  you can always check by doing out the multiplication.  Thus:  $(1-6)\times (5+7)=-5\times 12=-60$ so you are claiming that $-60\equiv 6 \pmod {11}$.  But this is true since $-60-6=-66$ which is certainly divisible by $11$.

Answer (score 0):

community wiki post so that the question can be closed

Yes, as stated in the comments, your approach is correct.